# Faster methods for loops

Tags: numpy, loops

In my dataframe, I have to repeat the same function 300000 times, each time adding 1 to a variable var. The easy way for me to do this is by using a for loop

```
for var in range(0,300000): 
    function(arg1,arg2,var,arg4,arg5)
```

All I need is to add 1 to `var`, not the rest of the function. Is there a faster way to iterate this? (I don't really know if is important in this case, but my function is doing its thing over a np.array)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, why can't you write `var += 300000`?

Comment: What’s arg1, arg2, arg4, arg5 and “function”?